# Does Surface 3 Require Admin Privileges To Connect Bluetooth Keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, administrator, microsoft-surface, peripherals

I have a Surface 3 (non pro) with Win 10 that belongs to my company for work, thus I don't have access to the Admin account, but I would like to use a bluetooth keyboard like [this Logitech unit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0148NPH9I).  Can I pair them and enable the new kb without the Admin password?

Edit: it appears there is insufficient info in the question to provide an answer; so alternatively is there some way to discover this without having a bluetooth kb on hand?

Comment: I would say, ask your admin.

Comment: If user level accounts can do it they'll say yes, if it needs admin level they'll say no.  I am trying to find out what level one needs before I buy one and have it not work.

Comment: This entirely depends on the specific configuration implement by your network administrator.  We cannot say for certain one way or another.  Surface 3 runs a normal x86 version of Windows and can be joined to a domain, how that domain is configured, cannot be determined by the information you provided.  *Ask your IT administrator if it will work*

Comment: I still don't understand why you won't just ask them.

Comment: @Xavierjazz they are hard to reach and not pleasant to work with, I'd rather not.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, that info mostly answers the question.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I called and spoke with IT.  They don't know, and don't know how to find out.